# Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl - how do I check current version of libcurl

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, build, libcurl

(new to Linux/Unix)

I have a build script trying to download a .tar.gz package, I get the following error

```
Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

I saw that this error can be due to single quote instead of double quote on the https address, but in the script there seems to be double quotes.

I saw that this error can be due to missing the "right" ssh version of libcurl.

How to I check which version of libcurl I am using ? How do I change option to support https ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because people on https://askubuntu.com or https://superuser.com/ are more likely to know the answer.

Comment: Since you're on Unix, use pkg_info

Comment: I doubt "https" is disabled in libcurl in Ubuntu. Show us a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the version of curl by running:

```sh
curl --version
```

If curl is not working for you, you might want to try [wget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) instead. Wget is commonly used for downloading files from web servers, and it has a similar feature set to curl.

```sh
wget https://example.com/example.tar.gz
```